# Required item not in soup object - BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I want to extract "bilibili-player-video-info-people-number" from this link:
https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1a44y167wK.  When I create my beautifulsoup object and search it, this class is not there.  Is it due to the parser?  I did try lxml and html5lib but neither did any better.

```
<span class="bilibili-player-video-info-people-number">585</span>
```

That's the full element that I want to extract - the number updates every minute to show how many people are viewing currently.

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import re
import html5lib

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Rob\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1a44y167wK')

content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html5lib')

viewers = soup.findAll('span', class_='bilibili-player-video-info-people-text')

print(viewers[0])
```

`print(viewers[0])` returns an out of range error as there is nothing in the viewers object.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you check that you get what you expect in the `content` variable?

Comment: many thanks for this hint - dear tobias. Awesome - a great asset for learing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost the entire site is behind `JavaScript` so `bs4` is useless, unless the element you want *is* in the requested `HTML`. In your case, *it's not*.

However, there's an API endpoint that you can query that carries this data (and much more).

With a bit of `regex` and `requests` you can get the online count (of viewers).

Here's how:

```py
import re

import requests

with requests.Session() as connection:
    page_url = "https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1a44y167wK"
    page = connection.get(page_url).text
    cid = re.search(r"cid\":(\d+),\"page", page).group(1)
    aid = re.search(r"aid\":(\d+),", page).group(1)
    url = f"https://api.bilibili.com/x/player/v2?cid={cid}&aid={aid}&bvid={page_url.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]}"
    print(connection.get(url).json()["data"]["online_count"])
```

Output (note: it might change, as viewers come and go):

```
562
```

Comment: Is it possible to fetch the rendered HTML via Selenium?

Comment: @tobias yes, it's possible.

Comment: I assume that is why he is using the `selenium` package. Perhaps you could add how to do that to the answer?

Comment: Hmmm...almost all of the stuff I wanted (likes, coins, comments etc) was available so I just assumed this would be, too.  How very irritating!  Can you show me how to do it with selenium as well?  That API get looks pretty complicated!

Comment: hello baduker - many thanks for this hint - dear tobias. Awesome - a great asset for learing! Your ideas and concepts were great stuff for all who wants to dive into Python. Keep on with your great project - you are a awesome supporter here!

Comment: I think you want to replace the url used within `page_url` with this `https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1a44y167wK` to get the correct numbers. The rest should be as they are @baduker.

Answer (score 1):

I did manage to solve this as follows:

```
    html = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
    start = re.search('<span class="bilibili-player-video-info-people-number">(.*)</span>',html)
```

The first command gets all the html from the webpage and stores it in a string called html, the second command searches for the very specific piece I wanted and finds the numbers in between.  Not sure if this is the best way but it worked and thank you to everyone who commented.